# How to install stardict from a tar.gz manually ?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, tar

I have downloaded stardict-2.0.0-pre2.tar.gz and applied the extraction on it by writing: tar xzvf stardict-2.0.0-pre2.tar.gz , thereupon a new folder was created with the following content:

[image]

From this point on, I am clueless how to proceed, only thing I have read is that sometimes a certain file has to be made executable by using chmod +x file.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if `INSTALL` contained some **INSTALL**ation-related information... or if `README` had any information worth **READ**ing... Or maybe we could just [ask a friend](http://goo.gl/RRGF6p).

Comment: I have tried : cat INSTALL README , both are empty and 0 bytes long

Comment: Does your distribution not have a binary package of this? And what is your distribution?

Comment: I have Linux Mint Rebecca, I do not know what a binary package is.

Answer (score 4):

It could be that `stardict-2.0.0-pre2.tar.gz` and `stardict-2.0.0.tar.gz` are just not functional.  I attempted to install both on `CentOS 5.6` without success.  The `INSTALL` and `README` are indeed empty on the `pre2.tar.gz` version.  Unless you specifically need this version I recommend installing `stardict-2.4.8.tar.bz2` instead.

```
wget https://stardictproject.googlecode.com/files/stardict-2.4.8.tar.bz2
tar jxvf stardict-2.4.8.tar.bz2
cd stardict-2.4.8
```

From there you can view and follow the `INSTALL` document.  I was able to `./configure` and `make` 2.4.8.  I did not complete the process with the `make install` however.